# Eventlistener handling on stacked/overlapped canvas elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have 3 canvas that are overlapped, they are in a div ( canvasContainer). the div contains some event-listener, so does the first canvas. I want the last canvas to be on the top of the 3 canvas, but still listen to the event of the first canvas. I don’t want to use the z-index parameter.

```
<canvas width="512" height="512" id="canvasXTKP" style="position: absolute; display: block; opacity: 0.8; width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor:        default;"></canvas>
<canvas width="512" height="512" id="imageView" numcanvas="15" style="overflow: visible; position: absolute;"></canvas>
<canvas width="512" height="512" id="imageTemp" style="z-index: 10; overflow: visible; position: absolute; cursor: auto;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS property pointer-events on the 2 canvas that should not listen to events, something like that :

```
pointer-events: none;
```

It should do the trick.